# Start flink local cluster with Docker, How can I set up log and stdout path?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I started Flink local cluster with Docker, In WebUI, TaskManagers's tab "Stdout" and "Logs" shows "Fetching TaskManager log failed.", How can I set up log and stdout path?

I use the following docker command to start Flink: 
`docker run --name flink_local -p 8081:8081 -it --rm flink local`

then I submit the WordCount.jar in WebUI(`localhost:8081`), Even if the job run success, but I can't see any result in WebUI TaskManager's log or stdout.

[Fetching TaskManager log failed. From Task Manager Logs Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVXBO.png)